# Twilio on cross platform mobile tools (Ionic, React-Native)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, react-native, twilio, messaging

I'm looking to build with Twilio's IP Messaging APIs using a cross mobile framework like React Native or Ionic. My question is - is this a sane request? I see that Twilio has a Javascript library that I plan to use. Examples of successes/failures would also help.

My overall goal is to build in simple chat rooms cross platform.

Comment: We're using Twilio right now, but we're implementing the Native iOS SDK with React Native. We are now considering moving to the JavaScript SDK to take advantage of services like code-push, so I would be interested to hear of any success you may have implementing the JavaScript SDK, and I'll keep you posted if we end up doing so and having any success.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll have feedback on the JS approach in the next few days. Feel free to comment here so others can piggyback.

Comment: Hey @sparkFinder, what was your experience using the JS SDK like? any code or advice you can share? I'm using React Native and am really interested in this

Comment: You have to build a native module. One major issue (that I've communicated to the Twilio team) is that their JS SDKs break when npm-V8 centric deps like 'crypto' can't be ported onto iOS' JavaScriptCore runtime. I've had to create a native iOS module to handle Twilio at the moment - though life would become way easier if the JS SDK worked in React Native.

Comment: We're about to start working on Twilio iOS with React Native --- have any of you published your solutions to open source? Thanks!

Comment: Can't add mine to OS. Check my answer. The solution isn't ideal but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution is to implement a native module for Twilio Messaging. Check Twilio's IPM docs for their iOS quickstart. There are too many libraries that the Twilio Node SDK uses that conflict with Apple's JavaScriptCore runtime.

Your native module would communicate with the React Native app through the RN bridge. At a high level you'd have to implement `sendMessage/joinChannel` from RN -> iOS and `receivedMessage/Channel` from iOS -> RN.

One example (that I've communicated to the Twilio team) is that their JS SDKs break when npm-V8 centric deps like `crypto` can't be ported. I'm guessing there are several other basic libraries that are commonplace in Node that don't get ported over by React Native's build system.

You can track related React Native issues here:
(Symptom - node modules are missing): https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else found their way here from a Google search, I recently released the code I developed to implement IP Messaging on React Native for my org. You can check it out at on GitHub: [react-native-twilio-ip-messaging](https://github.com/ccm-innovation/react-native-twilio-ip-messaging). It currently supports iOS with Android still in beta.

Comment: Update, Android has been released in addition with supporting newer versions of the SDK.