# Twilio IP-Messaging ing hybrid ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, twilio

Do we still need to use a native module to interact with twilio ip messaging in hybrid apps? I'd like to use it in a ionic app (chat with push etc.), but pure JS would be preferred.. All I could find about this was this thread [Twilio on cross platform mobile tools (Ionic, React-Native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212841/twilio-on-cross-platform-mobile-tools-ionic-react-native) but I was wondering if it is still needed to add native modules...

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio IP Messaging has a JavaScript library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/quickstart-js) which you could use as part of your Ionic application.

The only thing that would miss would be push notifications, which are [built into the iOS and Android SDKs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/push-notification-configuration). You could implement your own notifications (check out [Twilio Notify](https://www.twilio.com/notify) for an easy way to do that) but you would have to keep track of the online status of your users yourself and use the [IP Messaging webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/webhooks) to capture messages and notify your users yourself.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
But:
Please check my first link, which reads like the JS library is built for node.js and not really supported on mobile app frameworks.

Comment: Hi Phil, I am using twilio video-quickstart-js in Ionic 2, But when previewing camera(Android) its just showing an empty <video> tag, I am not able to see video content from front camera(Android) in this video tag. When connecting to twilio it says "Client is unable to create or apply a local media description". But its working on desktop browser

Comment: @mohit This is a question about IP Messaging. I would suggest that you open a new question rather than commenting on old ones. Whilst we're here though, it sounds like you're not getting permission from your browser on Android correctly. Are you testing the site on an HTTPS connection? If not, you'll need to. Let me know if you do open a new question.